# Bluetooth Chat for passing scores between two android devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm planning to implement a two-player functionality on my game and I'm currently modifying the BluetoothChat example in the Android SDK.. any ideas on how to pass the scores from one phone to another and compare them.

Comment: you can simply pass your scores with some identifiers so that you can match them. this score will be same as passing messages.

Comment: My aim is to pass score after the game is finished.. If time expires, the scores will be compared and there will be a need to determine who is the winner... What do you mean identifiers? I know identifiers can be a variable, method or something.. but how ??

Comment: @skygeek I need your help badly.. Please lend me a hand

Comment: what is the strategy of your game, means is it keeps the connection from starting of game to end OR you just need to make connection after finishing game.

Comment: you are connected from the start of the game

Comment: ok, you can do one thing. keep a byte inside your messages exchanging which identifies that the score is coming & just after the byte write score and get it over receiver end and compare it.

Comment: Do you have there the code of Android SDK's BluetoothChat... Can you please check it and kindly tell me where should I put what you're saying.. Thanks